# I don't know what it is

Tags: bmx

The body is white and there is a sign that has a HH on it and my grips say that it is a wethepeople . The rims are titanium blue , the handle bars are gray,and the forks are to

Comment: It will be good to rename the title to something more informing. Pictures will help.

Comment: I would guess that it's a bicycle.  But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Wethepeople is a brand. Is this what you mean? I don't really understand your question.

http://www.wethepeoplebmx.de